# How to set the RewriteRule (htaccess) for my subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i setup my htaccess on an subdomain, 
e.g. `xy.blub.com` that all requests will sent to the `index.php?page=`

I already tried this config :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule \.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|bmp|BMP|js|JS|css|CSS|swf|SWF|flv|FLV|mp4|ICO|ico|MP4|htc|HTC|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^ajax.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule   .* index.php?page=$0 [QSA,L]
```

The subdomain has a specific folder and when i try to open a link from my website, 
e.g. xy.blub.com/home , it always tries to look for an folder "home" in my subdomain-folder, instead of getting `xy.blub.com/index.php?page=home`

Comment: htcaccess is enabled, i got RewriteRule \.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|bmp|BMP|js|JS|css|CSS|swf|SWF|flv|FLV|mp4|ICO|ico|MP4|htc|HTC|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ - [L] in it and it refuses to access my css folder : /

Comment: Nope, everything is like before.

Comment: Try putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Ok, got no error here, so my htaccess is not accepted?

Comment: Yes that means your .htaccess is not enabled.

Comment: Just to make sure. You are talking constantly about "htaccess". But in your filesystem its is ".htaccess" right ? And you are using apache not ngnix?.

I know these are most likely stupid questions but at this point it is also important to make sure what the problem definitly is not.

Comment: Yepp, it is .htaccess and it is IIS (MS Server) so it should be Apache ^^

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

But keep in mind that this will work for all calls so also your js/css/images/icons etc.

So maybe als add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

As it will only execute the rule when the file does not exists.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: is what you updated in your question the only thing you tried or did you try the version as how i posted it ? (first thing i notice is that you still use rewrite rule instead of rewritecond thats why i ask)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer. Server is MS 2012, so there is not .htaccess support. I need to write the same rules with the IIS URL Rewrite - easy shit, if you know that MS Servers dont accept .htaccess files. Ty all for your help.